# Azure RM NSG Port Forwarding Not Working

Tags: linux, debian, powershell, azure

I have a Debian 6.x box that I needed to move to Azure.  Before moving it up, I did make sure that SSH is listening on any port, so is Apache.  My NSG has all of the right ports opened (22, 443 for now). I uploaded the VHD, then used the following PowerShell commands to create the VM based off of the VHD:

```
$vnet = get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VnetName -ResourceGroupName $VnetRG
$subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "$SubnetName" -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name "$pipName" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "$NSGName" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $nicName -Subnet $subnet -Location $location -PrivateIpAddress $newVMIP -DnsServer $dnsServer1,$dnsServer2 -PublicIpAddress $pip -NetworkSecurityGroup $NSG
$newVM = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $newVMName -VMSize $newVMSize | Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id | Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VhdUri $vhdPath -Name $diskname -CreateOption attach -Linux -Caching ReadWrite
New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $newVM -DisableBginfoExtension
```

I can see that the machine is running as I can view the auto-logged-in desktop in boot diagnostics.  However, when I try to SSH or when I try to access the web site over 22 and 443, it's not returning any response.  Telnet times out and it's acting like the port isn't forwarding at all.

I understand that because it's Debian 6.x, waagent isn't supported.  But I shouldn't need waagent for port forwarding, should I?  From what I understand about networking and from what I see in MSDN forums, "The port forwarding should be invisible to your end machine.  As the public hits the public port and your VM receives on the internal port." (https : //social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd93f5cb-a674-4b9c-aa5a-9f6e7b364f2c/port-forwarding-still-broken?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)

Did I mis-key or miss something in my PowerShell script?  Any ideas?

I have tried deleting and re-creating the VM and I've tried re-uploading the VHD file.  I did have to convert it from VHDX to VHD, but that shouldn't matter since it's actually booting up and I see the screen in boot diags.

The NSG I used does work for any other newly created machine via portal or PowerShell, just not this uploaded machine, which makes me think I've flubbed something in the script.  Everything does show that it's open for port 22 and 443 though.  Here's a screen grab of the Effective Security Rules blade:
[rules screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZhDD.png)

The iptables on the local machine are empty as shown in [this screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HCK7.png).

What's weird is that I can't SSH to it from another machine on the same virtual network either.  I tried going through the steps at https : //docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-debian-create-upload-vhd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json, but since it's Debian 6, the waagent won't install.  But again, I shouldn't need an agent on the machine for port forwarding to work.  No other virtualization technology requires an agent for NAT to work.

**Edit** - this was suggested as a duplicate of StackOverflow.  I originally asked the question there, but everyone suggested I post my question here.  So I did that, marking the StackOverflow answer as the answer.

Comment: @user7384527 You could create a new VM in azure portal and try to ssh your VM by using private IP.

Comment: @kaylum - Thanks for the heads-up.  I did as you suggested based on searches I did at Serverfault.  However, searching StackOverflow yeilded results for "[azure] port forwarding not working" as well.  So if it yielded results here and there, and this isn't the right place, I'm not 100% sure Serverfault is either.  But it sounds more (based on the name) like that's a better place for it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Walter - Sorry, just re-read your post.  No, I can't SSH or telnet to it using a different computer on the same subnet using a private IP either.  What could that mean?  While it's on-premise I can get to it from any computer, even NAT'ing through the internet.  Just not when I upload it to Azure.

Comment: @user7384527 You could ask the question on ServerFault.  Do you ensure there is no firewall block you on the VM? When you prepare the VHD, if possible, you could disable your firewall.

Comment: @user7384527 You could check your VHD as the link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-debian-create-upload-vhd?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json

Comment: I test in my lab. I uninstall waagent and recreate the VM, I could ssh the VM successfuly.

Comment: Could you use `netstat -ant` to check the ssh service in your original VM. The service should be listening on 0.0.0.0 `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  ` Please make sure the service is listening on ipv4 not ipv6. Also, please don't use `static` IP on your VM, you should use `dhcp` that Azure will assign IP automatically.

Comment: If you can't SSH to it from a VM on the same network then it's not an NSG issue, unless you added deny rules to the NSG. By default traffic from the local network is allowed.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - Thanks again.  I ran the netstat -ant and it has the entry for tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN, but it also has an entry for IPv6.  Would it be an issue listening on both?  It is set up for DHCP, and it is getting an address from Azure's DHCP.

Comment: @SamCogan - I tend to agree.  However, it works fine in Hyper-V, converted from VMWare Workstation on a different machine, even when I NAT it through my router.  The only time it breaks is after I upload it to Azure.

Comment: I'm becoming more and more convinced that I'm missing something on the Linux side.  But dusting off that cap, I have checked everything I know/remember.  Can anyone suggest anything else to look at in order to see why SSH, HTTPS, or any other ports (tried a Minecraft server on 22456 and it wouldn't work) aren't going through to the Linux box in Azure?  The NSG works, I verified it by connecting it to a new machine I created in Azure.

Comment: @suprphrk ssh service is right. You had better close your original VM when you start Azure VM.

Comment: @suprphrk Do you configure `/etc/resolv.conf`? I test in my lab, you could delete it. If you use `dhcp`. It will create the file automatic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [azure port forwarding not working](http://serverfault.com/questions/825057/azure-port-forwarding-not-working)

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - I don't understand the "ssh service is right" response.  As far as the resolv.conf, I tried deleting that on the source machine before uploading again tonight, but that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: @James - I originally asked it in StackOverflow, but everyone there suggested I put this in ServerFault instead, so I marked the StackOverflow answer complete.  My issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: I just tried removing vmware tools, removing the resolv.conf file, re-converting, uploading, and creating the vm again using the same commands, and I still can't SSH in.  I took Apache out of the equation as well, so now I'm just trying to SSH in.  Does anyone know a surefire way to tell where it's getting hung up?

Comment: I found a bit more information and a HUGE part of the problem.  When I convert from VMWare to Hyper-V, the network card is getting lost.  All I have is lo and pan0.  According to https://wiki.debian.org/WindowsServerHyperV , I need to add the network card, but I don't know how to do that in Debian 6.  Can anyone help with that?

Comment: I added a "Legacy Network Adapter" in Hyper-V, and now it found eth0.  Is there an Azure RM Equivalent of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 6 won't work in Azure.  You have to use "Legacy Network Adapter" in Hyper-V, and that doesn't work in Azure.  Or, you'd have to recompile the kernel to support the Hyper-V drivers for the NIC, and that's not recommended either.  Looks like I have to try to migrate the data to a new server.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, please ensure there is no firewall in VM block you to access your VM. Also, you could check whether you have NGS rules associate to Vnet’s subnet.

**Notes: NSG could associate to VM and subnet.**

More information about how to manage NSG please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations).

Also, you could check your prepared VHD as the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-debian-create-upload-vhd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've flagged this to be moved to Serverfault, if not I can as easily copy/paste it over.  Just FYI, the IPTables on the Linux box before I move it up are:

        Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
        target     prot opt source               destination         

        Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
        target     prot opt source               destination         

        Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
        target     prot opt source               destination

*edit* - and of course that didn't show up correctly.

Comment: Re: the prepared VHD - Ya, I did that one.  But it's Deb 6, so the tools under the "Manually Prepare" section won't go on it.  But I would be REALLY aggravated if I had to have the waagent installed in order for port forwarding to go through.  No other virtualization technologies require an agent for port forwarding to work, I don't see why Azure would.

Comment: Marking as the answer just for the "Post to Serverfault" suggestions.  Thanks all!